# Как использовать select в парсинге Python

Tags: python, парсер

> Задача: 1) Создайте словарь, где ключами будут названия телефонов из
> урока, а значениями будут их цены.
>
> 2. Выведите его в консоль, чтобы убедиться, что всё правильно.
>
> Примечание: разумеется, цены этих телефонов надо вытащить с сайта,
> используя показанные в уроке инструменты для парсинга.

Вот сам сайт: https://www.ozon.ru/category/smartfony-15502/huawei-26303185/?from_global=true&text=huawei

Я уже пытался начать делать, однако столкнулся с непониманием указания элемента парсинга.

Вот мой ущербный код:

```
import requests, bs4

url = "https://www.ozon.ru/category/smartfony-15502/huawei-26303185/?from_global=true&text=huawei"
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'UTF8'

b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

atitles = b.select("div.hk8 span")

titles = []

for a in atitles:
    titles.append(a.getText())

print(titles)
```

Comment: Вас "обманули", современный озон не парсится "показанными в уроке инструментами", если это те инструменты которые Вы использовали в своем скрипте... А через 5-10 запросов еще и капчу попросит. В ответе привел пример как достать HTML. Ну аж как его парсить, тут уж сами. Там ничего сложного.

Answer (score 0):

## Вариант без сопоставления данных, на ответ не претендует. Демонстрирует как достать HTML с озон

```py
from pprint import pprint
from unicodedata import normalize

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()

ua = UserAgent()

response = s.post(
    'https://www.ozon.ru/category/smartfony-15502/huawei-26303185/?from_global=true&text=huawei',
    headers={
        'User-Agent': ua.chrome
    }
)

response.html.render(
    sleep=10,
    scrolldown=True,
    keep_page=True
)

soup = Soup(response.html.raw_html, 'html.parser')

pprint(
    dict(zip([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.find_all('span', class_='f-tsBodyL')],
    [normalize('NFKC', item.get_text(strip=True)) for item in soup.find_all('span', class_='ui-a7a')])),
)
```

> Через 5-10 запусков просит капчу, идем в браузер вводим капчу руками.